# Not calls \everypar command after enumerate environment

Tags: luatex

Why when i use enumerate environment,command \everypar not call. I use \everypar inside our package and i need,that everypar calls even after enumerate environment. Help me please solve this problem. Thanks everybody very much for the help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\logging}{\message{new paragraph}}
\begin{document}
\section{test}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\item new test
\end{enumerate}
\everypar{\logging}

Test

New test

test again
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\everypar` is used quite extensively in LaTeX.

Comment: latex lists control whether they are a display and the  following text should be a new paragraph, or an in-paragraph list where the following text is a continuation of the paragraph before the list. It has to set `\everypar` internally to handle this, `\everypar` is set for similar reasons after section headings and lots of other places.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to handle such conflicts is to hide the original `\everypar` and make it display two token lists a new `\everypar` (that will be set by latex) and a `\myeverypar` that you can set:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldeverypar\everypar
\newtoks\everypar
\newtoks\myeverypar
\oldeverypar{\the\everypar\the\myeverypar}
\newcommand{\logging}{[here]\message{new paragraph}}
\begin{document}
\section{test}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\item new test
\end{enumerate}
\myeverypar{\logging}

Test

New test

test again
\end{document}
```

I added a typeset `[here]` in this case to make it easier to see which paragraphs triggered the `\logging` command, just for debugging.

Comment: after few nonths i desided to back to this question. I have a questions about your code:
1. what replacement of \newtoks command,or this command haven't any analog in expl3? 2. Why we use \mypar after end of the list. How we can "say" latex,that latex use \mypar instead of \everypar. 3. Whether \mypar will works,if we inserted it also after some second list,if it will be in document? 4. Why after end of list latex not use \everypar (where i can see source,to look how latex do it)? p.s. May be exists some manual,how to replace latex commands and other things by expl3 functions?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy expl3 doesn't use toks registers and document level things like everypar and lists are not covered by the core programming level constructs in expl3 either so now this has to be in classic latex2e code really.

Comment: Ok,do you plan in future implement it in expl3. 2. How i can to know or may be try to guess in future,such commands have expl3 analogs,and such kno? 3. I not understood,why after end of the list latex use \mypar instead of \everypar command and why it's ignore \everypar command?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy You asked about how to use `\everypar` (a TeX primitive) in combination with a latex2e list, expl3 really isn't involved at all. early versions of expl3 did use token registers but they are not really needed in etex as a general feature and they were dropped. The point of my answer was that in the context you asked about it is better to define your own `\myeverypar` command rather than directly use the primitive `\everypar` so I just used `\myeverypar` at that point as that is where you had used `\everypar`

Comment: I asked about expl3 variant,because i want to use it in our package,which use expl3 features,so imho its better,that in package i have as more expl3 code,as possible,but if this command haven't expl3 analogs,no problem. About everypar,i not undestood,why we use \newtoks instead of redefining of existing command and how we do,that instead of everypar it's call \myeverypar for each paragraph of document,even after the second \enumerate. Because after \section we can simple use \everypar{\cmd},but for lists it not works and what diferents between \newcommand and \newtoks commands?

Comment: I understood,what \newtoks command create new token list,but i am not understood why we should create new token list,because tl \everypar exists,but without \newtoks{\everypar} your code not works. also i not understood,why we use \the command inside \oldeverypar command and why for each paragraf latex call \myeverypar instead of \everypar? How can i see,how latex works with lists,and what happends with \everypar after end of the list? Thanks.

Comment: Where i can see source of the \list environment?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy  `texdoc source2e` then look at  ltlists chapter (F)

Comment: When i can find texdoc?

Comment: texdoc is the standard documentation command in texlive and I believe miktex as well, there is an online version at https://texdoc.net/